# Elasticsearch named queries inside hasParentQuery does not work?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I made a test to test that I get the correct named query inside a hasParentQuery. But it seems that it does not work.

Running elasticsearch 2.4, I cannot find any information about it. Or could it be that it's a bug?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html

**Output**

```
parent
outerBool
// "innerBool" and "term" should also be here?
```

**JSON Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "has_parent": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": {
                "term": {
                  "value": {
                    "value": "1",
                    "_name": "term"
                  }
                }
              },
              "_name": "innerBool"
            }
          },
          "parent_type": "branch",
          "_name": "parent"
        }
      },
      "_name": "outerBool"
    }
  }
}
```

**And the test:**

```
client.admin().indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest("my_index")).actionGet();

String employee =
    IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("employeeMapping.json"));
client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("my_index")
    .setType("employee").setSource(employee).execute().actionGet();
String branch = IOUtils.toString(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("branchMapping.json"));
client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("my_index").setType("branch").setSource(branch).execute()
    .actionGet();

String parentId = "1";
client.prepareIndex("my_index", "branch", parentId)
    .setSource(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("value", "1");
        put("value2", "2");
    }}).execute().actionGet();
client.prepareIndex("my_index", "employee", parentId)
    .setSource(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("id", "1");
    }}).setParent(parentId).execute().actionGet();

Thread.sleep(1000);

SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("my_index").setTypes("employee").setQuery(
    QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(
        QueryBuilders.hasParentQuery("branch",
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("value", "1").queryName("term")).queryName("innerBool")

        ).queryName("parent")
    ).queryName("outerBool")
);
SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

Arrays.stream(searchResponse.getHits().getHits()[0].getMatchedQueries()).forEach(q ->
    System.out.println(q)
);
```

**branchMapping.json**

```
{
  "properties": {}
}
```

**employeeMapping.json**

```
{
  "_parent": {
    "type": "branch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add inner_hits to the parent query, so that innerHits element in the response as added and I could get the matchedQueries from there.

```
QueryBuilders.hasParentQuery("branch",
   QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
      .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("value", "1").queryName("term")).queryName("innerBool"))
   .queryName("parent")
   .innerHit(new QueryInnerHitBuilder())
```